# help me "dry" out this .net XML serialization code

Tags: c#, refactoring, xml-serialization, dry

I have a base collection class and a child collection class, each of which are serializable.  In a test, I discovered that simply having the child class's `ReadXml` method call `base.ReadXml` resulted in an `InvalidCastException` later on.  First, here's the class structure:

**Base Class**

```
// Collection of Row objects
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("Rows")]
public class Rows : IList<Row>, ICollection<Row>, IEnumerable<Row>,
    IEquatable<Rows>, IXmlSerializable
{
    public Collection<Row> Collection { get; protected set; }

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        reader.ReadToFollowing(XmlNodeName);
        do
        {
            using (XmlReader rowReader = reader.ReadSubtree())
            {
                var row = new Row();
                row.ReadXml(rowReader);
                Collection.Add(row);
            }
        } while (reader.ReadToNextSibling(XmlNodeName));
    }
}
```

**Derived Class**

```
// Acts as a collection of SpecificRow objects, which inherit from Row.  Uses the same
// Collection<Row> that Rows defines which is fine since SpecificRow : Row.
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("MySpecificRowList")]
public class SpecificRows : Rows, IXmlSerializable
{
    public new void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        // Trying to just do base.ReadXml(reader) causes a cast exception later
        reader.ReadToFollowing(XmlNodeName);
        do
        {
            using (XmlReader rowReader = reader.ReadSubtree())
            {
                var row = new SpecificRow();
                row.ReadXml(rowReader);
                Collection.Add(row);
            }
        } while (reader.ReadToNextSibling(XmlNodeName));
    }

    public new Row this[int index]
    {
        // The cast in this getter is what causes InvalidCastException if I try
        // to call base.ReadXml from this class's ReadXml
        get { return (Row)Collection[index]; }
        set { Collection[index] = value; }
    }
}
```

And here's the code that causes a runtime InvalidCastException *if* I do not use the version of `ReadXml` shown in `SpecificRows` above (i.e., I get the exception if I just call `base.ReadXml` from within `SpecificRows.ReadXml`):

```
TextReader reader = new StringReader(serializedResultStr);
SpecificRows deserializedResults = (SpecificRows)xs.Deserialize(reader);
SpecificRow = deserializedResults[0]; // this throws InvalidCastException
```

So, the code above all compiles and runs exception-free, but it bugs me that `Rows.ReadXml` and `SpecificRows.ReadXml` are essentially the same code.  The value of `XmlNodeName` and the `new Row()`/`new SpecificRow()` are the differences.  How would you suggest I extract out all the common functionality of both versions of `ReadXml`?  Would it be silly to create some generic class just for one method?  Sorry for the lengthy code samples, I just wanted to provide the reason I can't simply call `base.ReadXml` from within `SpecificRows`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the only difference is this line:

```
var row = new Row();
```

vs

```
var row = new SpecificRow();
```

So you could extract that into a virtual function, say, `MakeRow()`, and then `ReadXml()` can be without duplication.

Comment: The value of `XmlNodeName` will differ between base and child, too.  I like your idea, but what should the return type of `MakeRow` be?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you casting when the `Collection` can only contain `Row` objects? Maybe I'm missing something.

Update:

```
Collection[index] as Row;
```

Would get around the exception but it might still not result in what you want (ie: a null instead of a Row)

Update:

Would refactoring the base to:

```
    public void ReadXml<T>(XmlReader reader) where T : IRow
    {
        reader.ReadToFollowing(XmlNodeName);
        do
        {
            using (XmlReader rowReader = reader.ReadSubtree())
            {
                var row = default(T);
                row.ReadXml(rowReader);
                Collection.Add(row);
            }
        } while (reader.ReadToNextSibling(XmlNodeName));
    }
```

work for you?

Comment: Updated question.  `SpecificRows` acts as a collection of `SpecificRow` objects and `SpecificRow : Row`.

Comment: Yeah, I tried the `as` operator and didn't get the InvalidCastException, but I still got an exception when I got `null` instead of the `Row` I was expecting.

Comment: But yeah, I've fixed that problem--the cast isn't the question I'm asking.  I want to refactor the working `ReadXml` methods to where they still work but don't duplicate so much code.

Comment: Oh I understand now, I might have an idea that will help with that.

Comment: `default(T)` will return `null` if `T` is a reference type

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this you can...

```
public void ReadXml<T>(XmlReader reader) where T : IRow, new()
{
    reader.ReadToFollowing(XmlNodeName);
    do
    {
        using (XmlReader rowReader = reader.ReadSubtree())
        {
            var row = new T();
            row.ReadXml(rowReader);
            Collection.Add(row);
        }
    } while (reader.ReadToNextSibling(XmlNodeName));
}
```

Then as long as T is an IRow type and it has a default constructor this code will work. 
see [Constraints on Type Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx)

The other approach is to use a template method

```
public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader) 
{
    reader.ReadToFollowing(XmlNodeName);
    do
    {
        using (XmlReader rowReader = reader.ReadSubtree())
        {
            Row row = CreateRow();
            row.ReadXml(rowReader);
            Collection.Add(row);
        }
    } while (reader.ReadToNextSibling(XmlNodeName));
} 

protected virtual Row CreateRow()
{
    return new Row();
}
```

Then in

```
// Acts as a collection of SpecificRow objects, which inherit from Row.  Uses the same
// Collection<Row> that Rows defines which is fine since SpecificRow : Row.
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("MySpecificRowList")]
public class SpecificRows : Rows, IXmlSerializable
{
    protected override Row CreateRow()
    {
        return new SpecificRow();
    }   
}
```

If your `this[]` method is returning `Row` types, then you don't need to override it. The base class will already do that.

If you want the `this[]` to return a `SpecificRow`, then in this derived class it is safe to cast directly to that... However... Why would the code consuming this need to know what type of Row it's dealing with? If it does, then I would try applying "tell don't ask" to the Row object, so the consumer of the Row doesn't know what type of Row it is talking to, again removing the need for this method.